# error: conversion to non-scalar type requested

Tags: c

Após compilar o codigo aparece o seguinte erro:
error: conversion to non-scalar type requested
segue codigo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct No{
    struct No *proximo;
    struct No *anterior; 
    int val;
};

struct Lista{
    struct No *incio;
    int tamanho;
};

void incluir(struct Lista *lis, int valor){
    struct No novo = (struct No)malloc(sizeof(struct No));
    novo->val = valor;
    novo->proximo = lis->incio;
    novo->anterior = NULL;
    if(lis->incio != NULL){
        lis->incio->anterior = novo;
    }
    lis->incio = novo;
    lis->tamanho++;
}

int consultar(struct Lista *lis, int valor){
    struct No *inicio = lis->incio;
    int achou;
    achou = -1;
    printf("Tamanho da lista: %d\n", lis->tamanho);
    while(inicio != NULL){
        printf("%d, ", inicio->val);
        if(valor == inicio->val){
            achou = inicio->val;
        }
        inicio = inicio->proximo;
    }
    if(achou == -1){
        printf("\nValor nao faz parte da lista.\n");
    } else{
        printf("\nValor faz parte da lista.\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
    return achou;
}

void remover(struct Lista *lis, int valor){
    struct No *inicio = lis->incio;
    struct No *noRemover = NULL;
    if(inicio != NULL && lis->incio->val == valor){
        noRemover = lis->incio;
        lis->incio = noRemover->proximo;
        if(lis->incio != NULL){
            lis->incio->anterior = NULL;
        }
    } else{
        while(inicio != NULL && inicio->proximo != NULL && inicio->proximo->val != valor){
            inicio = inicio->proximo;
        }
        if(inicio != NULL && inicio->proximo != NULL){
            noRemover = inicio->proximo;
            inicio->proximo = noRemover->proximo;
            if(inicio != NULL){
                inicio->proximo->anterior = inicio;
            }
        }
    }
    if(noRemover){
        free(noRemover);
        lis->tamanho--;
    }
}
int main(){
    int opcao, valor, consult;
    struct Lista listagem;
    listagem.incio = NULL;
    listagem.tamanho = 0;
    do{
        printf("|||||||||||||||||\n");
        printf("||1 - Incluir  ||\n||2 - Consultar||\n||3 - Remover  ||\n||4 - Sair     ||\n");
        printf("|||||||||||||||||\n");
        scanf("%d", &opcao);
        if(opcao == 1){
            printf("Digite um valor a ser inserido: ");
            scanf("%d", &valor);
            incluir(&listagem, valor);
        } else if(opcao == 2){
            printf("Qual valor deseja consultar?\n");
            scanf("%d", &valor);
            consult = consultar(&listagem, valor);
            printf("Valor consutado: %d\n", consult);
        } else if(opcao == 3){
            printf("Digite um valor a ser removido: ");
            scanf("%d", &valor);
            remover(&listagem, valor);
        } else if(opcao == 4){
            printf("Encerrando.");
        } else{
            printf("Opcao invalida.\n");
        }
    } while(opcao != 4);    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A função [malloc](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/) (usada para alocar dinamicamente um espaço de memória), retorna o ponteiro/endereço de memória onde inicia o espaço alocado.

O que você faz em:

```
struct No novo = (struct No)malloc(sizeof(struct No));
```

É tentar transformar (*casting*) esse endereço em uma estrutura (*struct*), o que não é possível.

O que você deve fazer é trabalhar com esse endereço:

```
struct No *novo = malloc(sizeof(struct No));
```

E assim, deve resolver esse erro.